# Using time values in conditional statements with IF formula

Tags: google-sheets

Algorithm: if time is 9:00am, display 6

I used the if formulas but it keeps on displaying "x"
Time is in 24-hour format.

```
=if(G2=20,"6",if(G2=21,"12",if(G2=22,"18","x")))
=if(G2="20","6",if(G2="21","12",if(G2="22","18","x")))
=if(G2="22","6",if(G2=21,"12",if(G2=22,"18","x")))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

Instead using hours as integers in your test use them h/24 where h is the hour number, i.e.

```
=IF(A1=9/24,6,"x")
```

## Brief explanation

Google Sheets manages times as serialized dates where 1 day is an integer and 1 hour is 1/24 so, to test if a cell value is `9:00 a.m.` use `A1=9/24`